# How do I create response cards with Twilio Flex Webchat UI

Tags: twilio, amazon-lex, twilio-flex, twilioflexwebchat

I am using the [Twilio Flex Webchat UI library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/webchat/setup) that I am integrating with Amazon Lex.

I would like to render response cards based on Lex's [ResponseCards](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/ex-resp-card.html) feature, so basically present buttons for users to reply with instead of relying on free text.

I can see that the Twilio Help Center uses response cards with their own web chat, but I cannot find support for it in the Twilio Webchat documentation.

[image][image]

Comment: did you find a decent answer from Twilio about this ?